# I want to connect to sql server with express Is the problem from sql server or my code?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

**What do you think is the problem?

This is the output. Is there a problem with my configuration file?**

.The desired port is set to 5000.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   
    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'Ali137212',
        server: 'DESKTOP-1E5O0MD', 
        database: 'ReactShop',
        port : '1433' 
    };
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
           
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('SELECT * from Table_Laptop', function (err, recordset) {
            
            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

**Thank you for helping me. I'm very stuck**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66xwO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCRCN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co7dQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the images attached with your question, it looks like this isn't a SQL connectivity issue, and is more to do with port `5000` already having a running process.

The problem is most likely that you started the server at one point recently without properly stopping it, and now the process is stuck running.

What you need to do is locate the process running on your machine, get the PID (Process ID), and run a command to kill the process.

This is the solution to kill a process, at least for Windows.

1. Run `netstat -ano | findstr 5000` in your terminal.
2. Something similar to the following output should appear:
   `TCP 0.0.0.0:5000 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 6260`
3. Grab the number on the far right, in my case it was `6260`. This is the PID.
4. Open Command Prompt and type `taskkill /F /PID 6260`, replacing `6260` with your PID.
5. You should see something like `SUCCESS: The process with PID 6260 has been terminated.`.

If none of the above steps work, consider changing your port from `5000` to something like `3000` for the time being, and wait for the process on port `5000` to die off organically.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem was not solved and it still gives this error

Comment: @aliesmaily Can you please make sure the port number you are using is not surrounded by quotes?